# Android ActionBarCompat back button icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, icons, android-resources, homescreen

I searched around but I have not yet found a way to change the icon of the button `android.R.id.home`. 
Is there a way? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the home view because it exists above the content view and in the window decoration. You can supply a custom navigation view which mimics the home view (e.g., has your app icon in it). Try actionbar sherlock, i've heard things about it but never tried it.